# How can I use library which is built using 2.9.2 in project which is built using 2.10.1?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-2.10

How can I use library build against 2.9.2 in project which is built using 2.10.1 ?

In particular I'm trying to use **[salat](https://github.com/novus/salat)** and get following exception

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.novus#salat_2.10;1.9.2-SNAPSHOT: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:214)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:114)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:114)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:102)
    at sbt.IvySbt.liftedTree1$1(Ivy.scala:49)
    at sbt.IvySbt.action$1(Ivy.scala:49)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:58)
```

Comment: can you provide full sbt build configuration?

Comment: @SergeyPassichenko sure. http://pastebin.com/M9SpiuQN

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Major versions of Scala are binary incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

You can. Just use OSGi. Use Scala 2.9.x with one bundle, use Scala 2.10.x with other. Work with multiple incompatible binary dependencies within single execution environment is one of the situations for which OSGi was created. Scala jar already packed as bundle. Everything ready.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the library version, built against 2.10. The artifact, you are using seems to be incorrect though. In your `build.sbt` try changing `"com.novus" %% "salat" % "1.9.2-SNAPSHOT"` to `"com.novus" %% "salat-core" % "1.9.2-SNAPSHOT"`. Here's the [full list](https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;gav~com.novus~salat%2a_2.10~~~) of artifacts available for 2.10.

Comment: I still get this :( `sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.novus#salat-core_2.10;1.9.2-SNAPSHOT: not found`

Comment: @ruslan Do you have sonatype snapshot repo in your resolvers? `resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"`

Comment: I don't but it doesn't work with it either. Plus isn't it necessary for sbt 0.11.2+ ? I'm using sbt 0.12.1

Comment: This is pretty strange. I've put up a test project, and it works just fine. Here: https://gist.github.com/folone/19d8dfe06af578723d05 Are you maybe behind a proxy, which does not allow accessing sonatype nexus?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me http://pastebin.com/yy6tGYDE

1. add `"Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"`
2. remove `"org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.6.0"` possible conflict, salat 1.9.2-SNAPSHOT uses 2.5.0
3. change `"com.novus" % "salat-core" % "1.9.2-SNAPSHOT"` to `"com.novus" %% "salat" % "1.9.2-SNAPSHOT"`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to recompile the library against scala 2.10 as the the scala-versions are binary incompatible with each major release. As from 2.9 to 2.10.